# Exporting a development django application to production

Tags: python, django, production-environment

I've been developing a django web-application for three months now, and I'd like to set it to production. I'm currently using South as database schema manager and I haven't got any clue on how to export my application databases schemas and content, and my project code to another directory; in order to set my production environment.

Any clue on how to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the approach documented [here](http://lincolnloop.com/django-best-practices/projects.html). With this arrangement, you have common, production, dev, and test settings. Works for me.

Comment: Not sure to fully understand everyting noticed here, now how to really setup multiple environments, but I'm gonna read it more carefully and'll tell you. 
Thank you for your help!

Comment: The link provided now just goes to a page with four links, the reader is left to piece together an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you meant, but if you are looking for ways to move your django app from development to production server, try [this](http://kencochrane.net/blog/2011/04/deploying-my-django-application-to-dotcloud/) or [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-django/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Steps to get your Django App from development to Production

1. open your project folder then find `settings.py` find the following line,

   ## SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!

   DEBUG = False

   Change the debug to false.
2. Change your db credentials with the actual production server db credentials
   in your `settings.py`

   DATABASES = {
           'default': {
               'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
               'NAME': 'seocrawler',
               'USER': '',
               'PASSWORD': '',
               'HOST': 'localhost',
               'PORT': ''
           }
       }
3. once done upload your project folder to the folder in server
4. open putty enter your server credentials, then a terminal or cmd will pop 
   up.
5. check python is installed on your server by executing below command in terminal  `python -V`
6. then check whether django is installed by running `django-admin --version`, 
   make sure that the django version you used to develop the project matches the one on server if not the install the specific version.
7. now using the `cd` command to go to the project folder which contains `manage.py` file.
8. now run `python manage.py showmigrations` this will list if any db migration is pending for your project.
9. now run `python manage.py makemigrations` this will migrate the db tables to production server database.
10. now run `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` then go to your domain like `www.example.com:8000` in browser, to test whether your site is working.
11. once your site is up and working we want python manage.py runserver command to run even after the terminal is closed (means python manage.py runserver command in as background task/process).
12. to do that run `nohup python manage.py runserver &` this will run command in background and will never die the process even when putty terminal is closed.
13. All done! now your server is up and your site too.
14. Enjoy!

Comment: While this is better than the accepted answer, it should really be noted that the built-in Django server should not be used in production. You should Apache or nginx.

Comment: Noted  Thanks :)